# Cannot assign read only Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this controller:

cart.js

```
var cart = angular.module('tutorialAngularApp');
cart.factory('Items', function () {


var items = {};
  items.query = function () {
    return [
      {title: 'Paint pots', description: 'Pots full of paint', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
      {title: 'Polka dots', description: 'Dots with polka', quantity: 17, price: 2.95},
      {title: 'Pebbles', description: 'Just little rocks', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
    ];
  };
  return items;
});

cart.controller('CartCtrl', function ($scope, Items) {
  $scope.bill = {};
  $scope.discount = {};
  $scope.items = Items.query();

  $scope.totalCart = function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.items.length; i < len; i++) {
      total = total + $scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity;
    }
    return total;
  };

  $scope.subtotal = function () {
    return $scope.totalCart() - $scope.discount;
  };

  $scope.calculateDiscount = function (newValue, $scope) {
    $scope.discount = newValue > 100 ? 10 : 0;
  };

  $scope.$watch($scope.totalCart, $scope.calculateDiscount);
});
```

And I am trying to show data in this html view:

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    <input ng-model="item.quantity">
    <span>{{item.price | currency | number: 2}}</span>

    <p></p>
    <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency | number: 2}}</span>

    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div>Total: {{totalCart() | currency}}</div>
  <p></p>

  <div>Discount: {{discount | currency}}</div>
  <p></p>

  <div>Subtotal: {{subtotal() | currency}}</div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I am getting error

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'discount'
```

Total value is calculated fine when each other variable is set. But I do not understand why this happens since it is defined correctly. This code is just par of Yeoman project. Anyone seems to know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem has to do with your function `$scope.calculateDiscount`.

`$scope.$watch` takes in two parameters, a variable and a function which has an `oldValue` and a `newValue` (Not `$scope`). Have a look [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html) for info on how to utilize `$watch`.

Comment: But how does this cause problem?

Comment: In your function calculateDiscount, imagine `50` being passed in for that second variable (In your case named `$scope`). You're trying to run the code `50.discount = whatever`

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for the $watch callback function is the old value, not $scope, scope is passed as the third parameter, so your calculateDiscount function could look like

```
calculateDiscount(newValue,oldValue,$scope)
```

But note since calculateDiscount will already have access to $scope, since it is defined in the outer function scope, you do not need the third argument.  So you could also just use

```
calculateDiscount(newValue,oldValue)
```

But if you had defined calculateDiscount outside of your controller than you would need to use the third argument.

[$watch reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)